# javascript and jquery weird array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrayobject

i have stuck on this weird thing for 03 day and don't understand why it created that object "id[]" when jquery sending data to server. i tried to push the element to new array so i can get the normal {id: 'value01'} but it does not work, the server response is still showing the weird array in object: {'id[]': 'value01}. i am stuck on this because if i do `var id = masoid[0]` it work as the server show normal {id: 'value01'} but i need to filter the array before sending it. Thank you for your time

here is jquery code

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
                function isNumeric(n) {
                    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
                }
                if(isNumeric(value)){
                    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
                }
            }; 

            // var id = {masoid.filter(onlyUnique)};
            // var idDaFilter = new Array;
            // id.forEach(element => {
            //     idDaFilter.push(element);
            // });
            var id = masoid.filter(onlyUnique);

            console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                url: deleteUrl, 
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id:id},
                });
```

the server response:
[image: serverresponse]

server code

```
let id = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        
        console.log(req.body);
```

Comment: well, the value of `id` will be an Array - is that not what you expected? If you check the browser developer tools, what does the request body actually look like there - your server code may be *doing something wrong™*, but the first step is to determine exactly what the client sends - and that's what the developer tools in your browser are there for ...

Comment: @JaromandaX in developer tool it showing me with the array prototype object but i don't understand why it created "id[]" not "id" itself and the req.body in server console log show that it have additional "[]" but in developer tool it show object array. i post server code already and it is just parse of req.body as i mentioned above.

Comment: `the array prototype object` well, an array can't be sent in a body - so, it's a string representation ... is it JSON? or x-www-form-urlencoded? or some other format? - Oh, and that one line is nowhere near enough server code ...

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry the output is in the server console log not the server response, it is www-form-urlencoded. i am reading back for the shallow coppy and  what about that one line? i acttually parse the request to server using that one line with express.js

Answer (score 0):

You're using the method *filter* in the variable **id**. This method return a new array (shallow of original), so this is why you're getting 'id[ ]' on response. Use *find* instead.

```
var id = masoid.find(onlyUnique);
```

See an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp).

When you set `var id = masoid[0]` you're getting the first element of that array, than it works.

See more details on documentation [find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: ah yeah it happen to be the shallow of copy. but on my array in case there are multiple value, the find method wont work but the filtter itself sent all the unique value to server, so how do i get rid of that object "id[]" ?. but thank you for your time, i will rereading about shallow copy and deep copy object later